# How to implement one validation message in checking all the required fields in ASP.net MVC 3?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I would like to ask some codes on how to implement one validation message in checking required fields of a model. For example:

I have a model named "AdminUsers" and having firstname, lastname, email, username and password properties. Then, all of these fields are required.

I need to show one validation message (says: "Please complete all fields marked with *") if some of them is not been supply and,

the label should be change to red if this field is not supply.

Please see below:

[image: Manage User]
Please advise.

Thanks.

Comment: So far I tried to create a Custom Validation attribute but I need to show only a group validation message as stated above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest that the best approach here would be to implement the **IValidatableObject** interface by your model (view model) object.